# Execute in delphi a curl code for connection to stripe payment

Tags: delphi, http, stripe-payments, indy, stripe-connect

I try to connect me to my stripe payment test account with delphi.

The connect API is here:
[Stripe connect API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/curl#authentication)
Curl example:

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges \
   -u sk_test_CpkBxhx9gcmNYYQTZIXU43Bv:
```

I tried using Indy TIdHTTP component with TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL
and calling post with Tstringlist or TIdMultipartFormDataStream as parameter
but I receive always response: 401 - Unauthorized

Here my code:

```
var   
   Data: TIdMultipartFormDataStream;
   https: TIdHTTP;
   ssl: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;

begin

https := TIdHTTP.Create(self);
ssl   := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(Self);
https.IOHandler := ssl;

https.Request.BasicAuthentication := True;

Data := TIdMultipartFormDataStream.Create;
//Data.AddFormField('api_key', 'sk_test_CpkBxhx9gcmNYYQTZIXU43Bv');
Data.AddFormField('apikey', 'sk_test_CpkBxhx9gcmNYYQTZIXU43Bv');
https.Post('https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges', Data);
Memo1.lines.Add( https.ResponseText );
Data.Free;
end;
```

Any help or suggestion would bee very appreciated.
Thanks,
Peter

Comment: how did you send cc info to stripe?  or did you not get that far yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must not use a form field to transfer the API key. Instead, set the Request.Username property. The password is empty, so Request.Passwort is unused. From the API docs on your linked [page](https://stripe.com/docs/api/curl#authentication):

> Authentication to the API occurs via HTTP Basic Auth. Provide your API
>   key as the basic auth username. You do not need to provide a password.

This example works with Indy 10.6.2 and OpenSSL libraries in the program folder:

```
program Project31229779;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  IdHTTP, SysUtils;

var
  HTTP: TIdHTTP;
begin
  HTTP := TIdHTTP.Create;
  try
    HTTP.Request.BasicAuthentication := True;
    HTTP.Request.Username := 'sk_test_CpkBxhx9gcmNYYQTZIXU43Bv';
    try
      WriteLn(HTTP.Get('https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges'));
    except
      on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
      begin
        WriteLn(E.Message);
        WriteLn(E.ErrorMessage);
      end;
      on E: Exception do
      begin
        WriteLn(E.Message);
      end;
    end;
  finally
    HTTP.Free;
  end;
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Note: you may also put the user name / password in the URL:

```
HTTP.Request.BasicAuthentication := True;
try
  WriteLn(HTTP.Get('https://sk_test_CpkBxhx9gcmNYYQTZIXU43Bv:@api.stripe.com/v1/charges'));
```

Comment: If you put a username/password in the URL, `TIdHTTP` will parse them out and put them into the `Request` properties before preparing the request for transmission.